# Network manager doesn't show mobile devices on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager

I have Kubuntu 18.04 Plasma. The GUI Network Manager shows only WiFi and wired connections. When I connect GSM modem it shows nothing new. On terminal after `nmcli` I can see this modem.

I tried with Huawei E173 and E180 and same result. In Ubuntu 16.04 both worked well.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I solved the problem. Installation of network-manager-gui helped.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155727/kubuntu-18-04-network-manager-not-shows-mobile-devices#comment1923241_1155727) from the author of this question, the solution is to install `network-manager-gui`.